# language-ext Task of Either with multiple from clauses

Tags: language-ext

I am learning FP with language-ext and I ran into a problem that I have not been able to overcome. I simplified my code down to this example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LanguageExt;
using static LanguageExt.Prelude;
using Xunit;

namespace Temp {

    public class SelectManyError {

        [Fact]
        public async Task Do() {

            var six = await from a in Task.FromResult(Right<Exception, int>(1))
                            from b in Task.FromResult(Right<Exception, int>(2))
                            from c in Task.FromResult(Right<Exception, int>(3))
                            select a + b + c;

        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Multiple implementations of the query pattern were found for source type `Task<Either<Exception, int>>`.  Ambiguous call to 'SelectMany'.

I understand what the compiler thinks the issue is from reading [this webpage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1940). But, I am clearly missing or not understanding something important because I cannot figure out how this error is caused by this scenario OR what to do about it. This will work just fine if it is only 2 from clauses, which confuses me even more.

Is this the wrong approach to this type of problem? Is there another way I am unaware of?

Comment: What version of Language Ext are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.0.19

Comment: > "I edited in the entire file, is it giving you the same error now?"

Thanks for the more detailed example.  Yes, I am now getting the same error as you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is having a hard time understanding what the type of `a` is supposed to be (either `int` or `Either<Exception, int>`) since it is unused on the second `from` line.

Here is a awfully ugly workaround for this specific case.  However, for any type, I think the hack can be adapted to work for that type.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LanguageExt;
using Xunit;
using static LanguageExt.Prelude;

public class Namespace
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Method()
    {
        var six = await from a in Right<Exception, int>(1).AsTask()
                        from b in Right<Exception, int>(a - a + 2).AsTask()
                        from c in Right<Exception, int>(3).AsTask()
                        select a + b + c;
    }
}
```

Comment: I created an issue on LanguageExt's GitHub about this behavior
https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/issues/476

Answer (score 4):

Lang-ext author here.  We've been discussing the issue on the [lang-ext github repo](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/issues/476).

These are my comments:

It's tough.  They're not really false positives to be honest, because `Either<L, R>` supports the `+` operator, and so the `SelectMany` that belongs to `Task<R>` will produce a valid result just like the `SelectMany` that works with `Task<Either<L, R>>`.

Basically the `a`, `b`, and `c` values could legitimately be `int` or `Either<Exception, int>` depending on which `SelectMany` implementation the compiler chooses.

The whole expression is valid for all `SelectMany` extensions, which is obviously why we have that ambiguity.

It's a shame that changing `var three = ...` to `Either<Exception, int> three = ...` doesn't change the inference system.  Because that's the key difference between the two possible expressions that the compiler is confused by.

One thing you might want to do instead of using `Task<Option<A>>` is use `OptionAsync<A>` and instead of `Task<Either<L, R>>` use `EitherAsync<L, R>`.  They're essentially exactly the same types, except it's got all the binding semantics wrapped up nicely so you'll never have this issue again.

I am going through the process of creating an `*Async` variant for all the monadic types in lang-ext.  For convenience, potential performance benefits, and to allow the equivalent of 3 nested levels of monads: `M<A<B<C>>>` for example a `Seq<OptionAsync<A>>` is the same as `Seq<Task<Option<A>>>`.

Anyway, back to your example above, you could instead do:

```
public async Task<int> Method()
{
    var six = from a in Right<Exception, int>(1).ToAsync()
              from b in Right<Exception, int>(2).ToAsync()
              from c in Right<Exception, int>(3).ToAsync()
              select a + b + c;

    return await six.IfLeft(0);
}
```

Or if you want to construct from a `Task<int>`:

```
public async Task<int> Method()
{
    var six = from a in RightAsync<Exception, int>(Task.FromResult(1))
              from b in RightAsync<Exception, int>(Task.FromResult(2))
              from c in RightAsync<Exception, int>(Task.FromResult(3))
              select a + b + c;

     return await six.IfLeft(0);
}
```

Or, you could stay inside the monad and return that:

```
public EitherAsync<Exception, int> Method() =>
    from a in RightAsync<Exception, int>(Task.FromResult(1))
    from b in RightAsync<Exception, int>(Task.FromResult(2))
    from c in RightAsync<Exception, int>(Task.FromResult(3))
    select a + b + c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to work around this is by using how the compiler searches for matching extension methods.

From the [C# spec](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/standard-v6/standard/expressions.md#11783-extension-method-invocations)

> The search [..] proceeds as follows:
>
> Starting with the closest enclosing namespace declaration, continuing with each enclosing namespace declaration, and ending with the containing compilation unit, successive attempts are made to find a candidate set of extension methods:
>
> If the given namespace or compilation unit directly contains non-generic type declarations Cᵢ with eligible extension methods Mₑ, then the set of those extension methods is the candidate set.
>
> If namespaces imported by using namespace directives in the given namespace or compilation unit directly contain non-generic type declarations Cᵢ with eligible extension methods Mₑ, then the set of those extension methods is the candidate set.

So .. if you add your own version of the extension methods needed for the LINQ query syntax to work (`Select` and `SelectMany`) within your application, at the same or a higher level in the namespace hierarchy as the calling code, these will be used and the two ambiguous versions in the `LanguageExt` namespace will never be considered.

Your extensions can just delegate to the generated source code in `LanguageExt.Transformers`.

Here I'm using `Task<Validation<` rather than `Task<Either<`; just check the [source-code](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/main/LanguageExt.Transformers/HKT/AsyncSync/HKT.AsyncSync.Extensions.cs) for the extensions class name of the particular combination of stacked monads you are using:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LanguageExt;

namespace YourApplication;

public static class BindDisambiguationExtensions
{
    public static Task<Validation<FAIL, B>> Select<FAIL, A, B>(
        this Task<Validation<FAIL, A>> ma,
        Func<A, B> f) =>
        ValidationT_AsyncSync_Extensions.Select(ma, f);

    public static Task<Validation<FAIL, C>> SelectMany<FAIL, A, B, C>(
        this Task<Validation<FAIL, A>> ma,
        Func<A, Task<Validation<FAIL, B>>> bind,
        Func<A, B, C> project) =>
        ValidationT_AsyncSync_Extensions.SelectMany(ma, bind, project);
}
```