# Refactoring method return value from async Task<Either<RouteError, object>> to EitherAsync<RouteError, object>

Tags: c#, language-ext

I'm prototyping `language-ext` and functional code style for a web server library to share between my projects. I really like binding of `async` steps using LINQ query syntax but I have now encountered this compiler issue: [language-ext Task of Either with multiple from clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247863/language-ext-task-of-either-with-multiple-from-clauses).

To implement the suggested solution in that link, I would need to refactor this method:

```
private static async Task<Either<RouteError, object>> DispatchRequest<T>(
    IRequestDispatcher requestDispatcher,
    T request)
    where T : class, IRequest
{
    var result = await requestDispatcher.Send(request);
    return result.Match<Either<RouteError, object>>(
        Some: x => x,
        None: () => new NotFoundError(),
        Fail: ex => new InternalServerError(ex));
}
```

where requestDispatcher is an implementation of:

```
public interface IRequestDispatcher
{
    Task<OptionalResult<object>> Send<T>(T request) where T : IRequest;
}
```

What I need is a method with this signature instead, so that it can be more easily used in LINQ expressions:

```
private static EitherAsync<RouteError, object> DispatchRequest<T>(
    IRequestDispatcher requestDispatcher,
    T request)
    where T : class, IRequest
{ 
  // What should the implementation look like? 
}
```

I can't figure out how to construct the method so that I can `await` and then return Left or Right based on the result. Everything I tried so far also looks ugly compared to the nice and clean original implementation with a `Task` return value.

Comment: What type does `IRequestDispatcher.Send` return?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `Send` returns a `TryOption`?  If so, then you can do this:

```
private static EitherAsync<RouteError, object> DispatchRequest<T>(
    IRequestDispatcher requestDispatcher, T request)
    where T : class, IRequest =>
        Send(request)
            .ToAsync();
            .Match(Some: Right<RouteError, object>,
                   None: () => Left<RouteError, object>(new NotFoundError()),
                   Fail: ex => Left<RouteError, object>(new InternalServerError(ex)))
            .ToAsync();
```

What that does is converts the `TryOption` to `TryOptionAsync` by calling `ToAsync` on the `Task<TryOption<object>>`, and then matches on that `TryOptionAsync` to return an `Task<Either<RouteError, object>>` and then finally calls `ToAsync()` on that to convert the `Task` to an `EitherAsync`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the signature of the request dispatcher interface in my question. It is now added to the question. What `Send` returns is actually `Task<OptionalResult<object>>`. If that is not recommended, I can change that as well.